# Android Animation Resources with constant velocity (zero acceleration)?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-resources

I have a **anim** resource which scrolls `TextView` (credits screen).

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="50000"
    android:fromYDelta="200"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toYDelta="-10000" />
</set>
```

I want to have constant transision speed with zero acceleration (same velocity over the whole animation period). I cannot find `android:interpolator` value that would allow that. Without `android:interpolator` value `translate` still uses some sort of acceleration profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@android:anim/linear_interpolator` for the interpolator.

Source containing list of available xml resources corresponding to common animators: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Interpolators

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is wrong way to do it. As the doc says it's "An interpolator where the rate of change is constant", but I want no rate of change (constant velocity).

Comment: In this context, "rate of change" being constant __is__ constant velocity. You would use an accelerate or decelerate interpolator if you wanted the velocity to increase or decrease during the animation.

Comment: If you want to compare interpolators easily, check out this fun little app I made (Android Studio + gradle project): https://github.com/stkent/InterpolatorMater